# CSS: background-image not loading?

Tags: css, background-image

Heyya,

I've just started writing a website (I'm still pretty new to learning web dev) and I'm having issues with getting a background image to load on a website despite looking around and trying a bunch of different things.

```css
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/Shadex1.png");
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
    position : absolute ;
    height: 50px;
    left : 0;
    top : 0;
}
```

The idea is to get the image to repeat and cover the nav bar and I've tried using both a png and svg files, but I just can't get it to work. I can load the images in the html file and that works fine so I know the file path is correct but CSS just isn't liking it so need a second pair of eyes to take a look.

Thank you for reading and any answers you might come up with.

Comment: The CSS stylesheet file often is in another directory than the HTML files, so judging the correctness of the filepath by its working from the HTML isn't really reliable... Meaning: Most likely it's a filepath problem.

Comment: Hi Johannes,
In this instance I have the CSS and HTML sitting in the same root folder so the path should work, I've also made it a relative path so that should work unless I'm mistaken?
Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `width` to `100vw` and is the uri correct?

Comment: I thought that as well, but unfortunately taking them out or swapping them for single quotation marks doesn't change anything.
Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: I've updated my ideas.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are able to load the image  `background-image: url("../images/Shadex1.png");` property. I think there might be chances that `url` is wrong. if you are getting an image correctly than just see below example.

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657037031161-d126c02cce8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw2fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh; /*I have added extra height for viewing image*/
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"></div>
```